# Why EF cannot translate query into sql

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Below I provide simple example to explain problem:
In db I have table Books

Id   Title Year Author

1     WarAndPease  1800 Tolstoy

2     Hobbit       1880 Tolkien

In code I add class

```
public class BookDto
{
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public string Author{get;set;}
}
```

Then I create List of bookDtos

```
IEnumerable<BookDto> booksInMemory = new List<BookDto>
{
    new BookDto{Title = "SomeTitle1",Author = "Author1"},
    new BookDto{Title = "SomeTitle2",Author = "Author2"},
}
```

Then I query books from db and mapping to bookdto

```
IQueryable<BookDto> booksInDb = context.Books.Select(b => new BookDto
{
 Title = b.Title,
 Author = b.Author
})
```

And I want to union books from memory with books from db on side of database

```
var allBooks = booksInDb.union(booksInMemory)
```

Writing this code I want that entity framework pruduce sql

```
select Books.Title,Books.Author from Books
union
select SomeTitle1 as Title,Author1 as Author
union
select SomeTitle2 as Title,Author2 as Author
```

But when I do toList , I get exception Unable to create a constant value of type.

Note:I know why exception is thrown,I have read about it a lot info.The question is why entity framework can't simply produce sql.

Comment: And the exception you get is....?

Comment: EF can't do produce SQL from classes that are outside of DBContext like BookDto... You cannot use new operator in Select from DBSet -> that's why you get exception

Comment: @Mario,at first time I hear that "You cannot use new operator in Select from DBSet",I have did it a lot times.And exception excatly not about it

Comment: sorry my mistake, you are right. One condition is that 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'